# Symfony 4: How to edit a given form control?

Tags: php, forms, twig, symfony4

I can create a form view and even edit a submitted one.
But how can I do if I need for example to edit **ONLY** an user email.

Here's basically what I try:

```
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_widget(form.id)}}
{{ form_widget(form._token) }}
{{ form_widget(form.email) }}
{{ form_widget(form.submit) }}
{{ form_end(form, {'render_rest': false}) }}
```

When I submit the form and `dump` the user after called `$form->handleRequest($request)`, all the rest fields are reset to them default values except the ones I rendered in my twig view (`id` `email`).

So what the right way to achieve my goal?

Comment: do you use the formbuilder? then make them other fields to hidden Type and require equals false

Comment: Yes I do use it. Should I use `hiddenType` when in another twig view, I would like to **ONLY** edit for example an user rank?

Comment: I'm wondering what if I had differents `FormType` accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

> I'm wondering what if I had differents FormType accordingly?

Dont know if this is the recommended way but it works!